# BGL edge bundled properties

Tags: boost-graph

I am using bundled properties, like this

```
class cVertex { ... };
class eEdge { ... };
typedef boost::adjacency_list <
    boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS,
    cVertex, cEdge  >
            graph_t;
graph_t myGraph;
```

This works nicely for the vertices.  I can write code to access the vertex bundled properties easily

```
const cVertex& v = myGraph[ *vertices(myGraph).first + idx ];
```

However, the same thing does not seem to work for edges

```
const cEdge& e = myGraph[ *edges(myGraph).first + idx ];
```

I get these compiler errors

```
1>.\cGraph.cpp(109) : error C2678: binary '+' : 
no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 
'boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<Directed,Vertex>' 
(or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

---

I have also tried this:

For vertices this works well

```
boost::graph_traits<graph_t>::vertex_iterator vi = vertices(myGraph).first;
vi += idx;
```

But this gives compiler errors

```
boost::graph_traits<graph_t>::edge_iterator  ei = edges(myGraph).first;
ei += idx;
```

Here is the error

```
>C:\boost\boost_1_51\boost/iterator/iterator_adaptor.hpp(330) :
error C3767: '+=': candidate function(s) not accessible
1>        could be the friend function at 'C:\boost\boost_1_51\boost/graph/topology.hpp(63)' :
'+='  [may be found via argument-dependent lookup]
```

Comment: Why are you trying to access edges by index?  That is the issue -- there is no way to advance an edge descriptor (as opposed to an iterator) by a certain number of steps.

Comment: So I can answer question such as: what is the value of bundled property x for the 15th edge?  In particular, I present the user with a table of edge properties and allow him the change the values of individual edge properties.  The table widget tells me that the value of a property for the 15th edge has just been changed.

Comment: In that case, you might want to have a separate, indexable data structure (such as an `std::vector`) containing the edge descriptors, then index into that.

Comment: I consider that storing the same data in two different containers is both inefficient and a breeding ground for bugs.  I will continue to use the workaround described in my answer.

Comment: At least if you are going to do that, use `std::advance` so that you would not need to modify the code to get full performance with edge iterator types that do have `operator+=`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`adjacency_list`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html) does not contain a single vector of edges for the graph, but stores the edges as an... adjacency lists. This means that each vertex stores its own edges as a list of adjacent vertices.

There are in boost many other data structures to represent a graph, e.g. the [`edge_list`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/edge_list.html) which will make your edges directly accessible, the [`adjacency_matrix`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_matrix.html) or the compressed sparse row graph (for fast and compact read only access).

You should also be able to solve your problem by creating a custom (property) map to directly access your edges.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I haven't worked on this for a couple of years, so I cannot give your answer all the attention it needs.  I wonder, if I were to change the adjacency_list to an edge_list would it not be so that I would solve the problem for edges but create the same problem for the vertices? In general, vertices and edges are of equal significance.

Answer (score -1):

I have found this workaround

```
boost::graph_traits<graph_t>::edge_iterator  ei = edges(myGraph).first;

for( int k = 0; k < idx; k++ ) {
    ei++;
}
```

It seems incredible that this is necessary!!!

As suggested by Jeremiah Willcock this code can be made to look simpler by writing

```
boost::graph_traits<graph_t>::edge_iterator  ei = edges(myGraph).first;
std::advance( ei, idx );
```

( In reality the code executed is the same, with the addition of a test on whether or not the iterator is random access and the function call itself )